# ¿Cuando hay onDestroy que pasa con las clases instanciadas en la actividad?

Tags: java, android

Buenas,

cuando un activity es destruido onDestroy que pasa con las clases que fueron instanciadas en este activity, ¿también se destruyen o quedan cargadas en memoria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[onDestroy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy())** Realice cualquier limpieza final antes de destruir una actividad. Esto puede suceder ya sea porque la actividad
>   está terminando (alguien llamó finish () o porque el sistema está
>   destruyendo temporalmente esta instancia de la actividad para ahorrar
>   espacio. Puede distinguir estos dos escenarios con el método
>   isFinishing ().

El método [onDestroy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()) en realidad es un metodo llamado por el sistema antes de que la actividad se destruya, lo cual podemos observar en el diagrama del ciclo de vida de la `Activity`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La ejecución de [onDestroy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()) se produce por dos situaciones:

- **a)** Porque se ha eliminado la actividad desde el propio código (llamando `finish()`)
- **b)** Porque el sistema operativo requiere memoria y está tratando de liberar memoria para uso en otras aplicaciones o el propio sistema.

---

De acuerdo a tu pregunta:

> cuando un activity es destruido onDestroy que pasa con las clases que
>   fueron instanciadas en este activity, ¿también se destruyen o quedan
>   cargadas en memoria?

supongo que deseas saber que sucede con clases que instanciaste, bueno en este punto al ser llamado [onDestroy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()) nos indica que la `Activity` esta a punto de ser destruida y los recursos liberados, en este caso las instancias de Clases serán destruidas.

Es importante saber que el Garbage Collector no libera estas instancias al instante.

Answer (score 2):

Depende, que tipo de variable declares. Si es una variable `static` esta es propia de la clase y se cargan (valga la redundancia) cuando se carga la clase y no cuando se instancia. Por otro lado, si dentro de la clase (o del método `onCreate` en este caso) declaras variables están viven y mueren dentro del ciclo de vida de tu `Activity`, una `Activity` tiene una instancia **única** y no puede haber dos instancias distintas.

Cuando la `Activity` esta "Detenida" pasa a segundo plano, ya que la `Activity` principal es otra, es **AQUÍ** donde mantiene todos sus datos tal y como estaban, todo en memoria. Pero el sistema es lo suficientemente inteligente como para eliminarla en caso que necesite espacio de memoria pues no esta anexada al administrador de ventanas.

Respecto al método `onDestroy()` es un método que se ejecuta ANTES de ser finalizada la `Activity` digo antes, porque para que se ejecute este método alguien o algo debió haber llamado a `finish()` o `finishActivity()` o porque el sistema esta liberando memoria que necesita.

Respecto a lo correcto, cuando una `Activity` pasa a segundo plano, es el metodo `onPause()` el que corresponde manejar los datos que hasta ahora, tu `Activity` mantiene, es aqui donde tu deberias saber que hacer con esos datos en el caso que por motivos de memoria se liberen, datos importantes y que afecten solo a esta `Activity`, por ejemplo la camara, animaciones, etc que se ocupan solo en esta instancia de tu actividad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Como primera aclaración, la actividad no se destruye en el OnDestroy(). OnDestroy es un metodo llamado por el sistema antes de que la actividad se destruya, este método sirve para que tu limpies lo que tengas que limpiar.

Que se destruya una actividad no implica directamente que se llame al GC (recolector de basura) sobre la actividad, pero si el sistema necesita memoria lo hará en cualquier momento, por lo tanto necesitas guardar todos los datos que no quieras perder.